# How to pass a reference of a hash and array to subroutine

Tags: perl

I am trying to pass a hash reference and array reference to subroutine but getting error like invalid class string:

```
sub test{
           if($chk == 2)
             {
                return(\%hash,\@array);
              } 
        }


my ($has, $arr)= test();
```

Now again i have to pass by reference to `"$has, $arr"` to a another subroutine.

How to do this? i was passing them like `\%$has, \@$arr` but it seems this is not the currect way to pass to a subroutine.

Comment: You are *"getting an error like invalid class string"*?  That's smacks of a Windows CLSID registration error, not a perlish error.  Can we please see the code that demonstrates the problem, rather than your narrative description of what you think you need to do to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
anotherSub($has, $arr);
```

`$has` and `$arr` are already references.

Answer (score 0):

my %Hash=('1'=>'one');

my @Arr=('1','2');

&fun(\%Hash,\@Arr);

sub fun(){

```
my $Hash_Ref=shift;

my $Arr_Ref=shift;
enter code here
&Fun2($Hash_Ref,$Arr_Ref);
```

}
sub fun2(){

```
my $Hash_Ref=shift;

my $Arr_Ref=shift;
```

}